# Basis Vector Confusion

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose $\mathbf{f}$ maps an open set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^m$, and $f$ is differentiable at a point $\mathbf{x} \in E$. Then the partial derivatives $(D_jf_i)(\mathbf{x})$ exist, and $$\mathbf{f}'(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{e}_j = \sum_{i=1}^{m}(D_jf_i)(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{u}_i$$
where $\{e_1, \cdots, e_n \}$ and $\{u_1, \cdots, u_m\}$ are the bases vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m$.

Rudin, theorem 9.17

I am a bit confused on the roles the basis vectors play in this theorem. Does anyone mind explaining a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The role of the basis is to fix some special directions, or informally coordinates. The reason this might not be apparent is that it is often implicit in who the function is written.

When you have some $f $ from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ say, and say you specify $f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (x_1x_2, x_3^2)$ then what you do is that you express the function with respect to the so-called canonical bases.

The element $x= (x_1,x_2, x_3) \in\mathbb{R}^3 $ is  $x_1 e_1 + x_2 e_2 + x_3 e_3$ where $e_1 = (1,0,0)$,  $e_2 = (0,1, 0 )$ and $e_3 = (0,0, 1 )$. 
While $f(x)= x_1x_2 u_1 + x_3^2 u_2$ with $u_1= (1,0)$ and $u_2 = (0,1)$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you quid!